# Reduction of Azure-cli docker image

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-cli

I am building a docker image with Azure-cli with alpine images but Azure-cli images increased the image size by 1.2 GB, how can I reduce the image size?

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /workspace

ENV PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION=ignore

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add git git-lfs zip bash aws-cli && git lfs install && \
apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python3 make g++ && \
apk update && \
apk add bash py3-pip && \
apk add --virtual=build gcc libffi-dev musl-dev openssl-dev python3-dev make && \
pip3 install azure-cli && \
apk del --purge build
```

Comment: we are also facing the same issue. no proper response from the Microsoft on this. I do not know what the world they need 1 GB for their CLI applications? 
I guess it is mostly because of their Python dependencies

Answer (score -1):

@raj03

The size of your container image is directly related to the size of the image you are using as a base image. In your case, you are using the Alpine image as a base image, which is a lightweight image. However, you are installing a lot of packages and dependencies on top of it, which is increasing the size of your image.

To reduce the size of your image, you can follow these steps:

Use multi-stage builds to keep the final image size small. Multi-stage builds make it easy to ensure that the final image contains only the artifacts you need for your application, and not any of the extra content that was required at build time1.

Remove unnecessary packages and dependencies from your image. You can use the --no-cache option with the apk add command to avoid caching the package index locally, which can help reduce the size of your image.

Use a smaller base image. You can use a smaller base image like alpine:3.13 instead of alpine: latest.

Comment: if i remove the azure cli related package, then the image size is only 180 MB but the moment i add the Azure cli-related package, the size increases to 1.5 GB.. so it has to be justified why we make this bulking image to just support the azure cli command